# Update Status in Android Facebook using Facebook Android library

Tags: android, facebook

I cant able to update the status in facebook using the facebook rocket library where i found fom http://www.androidpeople.com/android-facebook-api-example-using-fbrocket . Here i can able to create a facsbook api key from http://www.facebook.com/developers/apps.php. But still when I used the same key its getting logged in successfully but I cant able to update the status in facebook. But its working perfectly for the sample project from the same url which I mentioned first.

Can anyone please help to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance
Krishnakumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

facebook rocket is old i believe. there is a new official facebook sdk for android which you should have a look into.

[Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/)

[Facebook official blog](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/385/)

the example project there is pretty simple and this is easy to setup.